# How is autotools configured to build optional components only when dependencies are installed?

Tags: autotools

I have a C++ project using autotools as the build system.

My program involves an abstract interface, of which there are several implementations, with each implementation in a separate source file. These implementations depend on libraries which may or may not be installed, depending on user preference and platform.

I would like to configure autotools to skip building the implementations that are lacking the underlying dependencies. I'd like to do so in whatever way will be conventionally expected by users and package maintainers.

As an example, let's say my program outputs audio, and it can do so with [OSS](http://www.opensound.com/linux.html), [ALSA](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page), or [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/). These are implemented in `oss_output.cc`, `alsa_output.cc`, and `jack_output.cc`, respectively.

Currently my `Makefile.am` contains (among a few other things):

```
myprog_SOURCES = \
    src/oss_output.cc \
    src/alsa_output.cc \
    src/jack_output.cc

myprog_LDFLAGS = [...some other stuff...] -ljack
```

Unfortunately attempting to build this program on a system without JACK installed fails because the linker can't find libjack and/or the compiler fails because JACK's header files are missing. In the case JACK isn't installed, I'd instead like to drop `src/jack_output.cc` from `myprog_SOURCES`, and remove `-ljack` from `myprog_LDFLAGS`. And similar, for ALSA and OSS.

Of these dependencies (OSS, ALSA, and JACK), some of these libraries use `pkg-config`. Some do not, but I can still detect their presence by the existence of a header file and a library.

How is this accomplished with autotools, taking care to follow best practice and convention?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [autoconf/automake: conditional compilation based on presence of library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176929/autoconf-automake-conditional-compilation-based-on-presence-of-library)

Comment: Yes, looks like a good duplicate to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is this accomplished with autotools, taking care to follow best practice and convention?

There are two pieces:

1. Detecting which subsystems are wanted / supported, and
2. Limiting the build to only the selected subsystems.

### Identifying the subsystems to support

The first piece is Autoconf's bread & butter.  Typically, one would [check for the presence of each subsytem's library(-ies)](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html) via `AC_CHECK_LIB()` or `AC_SEARCH_LIBS()` to identify whether it is available, and also [check for the main header file(s)](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Headers.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fHEADERS-654) via `AC_CHECK_HEADER()` or `AC_CHECK_HEADERS()`.

It would be a convenience to also set up a mechanism for opting out of building support for some of the subsystems that are available.  That would take the form of setting up [`--without`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/External-Software.html#External-Software) or [`--disable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Package-Options.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fENABLE-1845) arguments (which of those to choose is often ambiguous).  This is not obligatory, but I would consider it good form.  Note, however, that it does require some care and attention to avoid including all found libraries in the link.

The Cadillac version would furthermore provide support for the user specifying where to find the wanted libraries and headers, in case they are not in the default search path.  I often do see this sort of thing in well-maintained projects, but it takes the complexity up a level, and I would not consider it in any way obligatory.

The implementation details could vary quite widely, but typically, the end result would be, for each subsystem,

- a shell variable indicating whether to include the subsystem in the build (maybe `build_oss`, for example), and
- (optionally) output variables (created via `AC_SUBST()`) conveying preprocessor / compiler / and or linker flags to be used to build against the the appropriate back-end library.  For instance, some or all of `OSS_CPPFLAGS`, `OSS_CXXFLAGS`, `OSS_LIBS` for the OSS piece.

### Limiting the build to selected subsystems

Automake and Autoconf work together on this.  The key tool is the [Automake conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).  Automake provides an Autoconf macro, `AM_CONDITIONAL`, for defining these and assigning their values, and it supports an `if` / `then` / `else` construct in `Makefile.am` files based on them.  (Note well that these are entirely separate from GNU `make` conditionals, though they have similar syntax.)

The section of the Automake manual I have linked refers to several others that discuss how conditionals should be used in various scenarios, and it's not entirely clear which of those apply to you.  My best guess, however, is that all you really need is [conditional sources](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Sources.html#Conditional-Sources), so that's what I'll focus on.

The Autoconf part would follow on from the bits I already discussed.  It might be as simple as

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([oss], [test "$build_oss" = "1"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([alsa], [test "$build_alsa" = "1"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([jack], [test "$build_jack" = "1"])
```

The Automake manual gives other examples.

On the `Makefile.am` side, that might match up with something like this:

```
myprog_SOURCES = \
  src/main.cc \
  src/another.cc \
  ...

if oss
  myprog_SOURCES += src/oss_output.cc
endif
if alsa
  myprog_SOURCES += src/alsa_output.cc
endif
if jack
  myprog_SOURCES += src/jack_output.cc
endif
```

You would need to take care of applying the per-subsystem flags and libraries, too.  You can take the same approach (and even use the same `if` blocks) as for the sources, and that would be just fine, or you could let `configure` take control through how (whether) it defines any flags for each subsystem in the first place.

You will have noticed that I glossed over many of the details.  This is a fairly high-level answer to what I have to take as a high-level question.  If I take the question any other way then it is too broad for this venue.

Answer (score 0):

The way to have selective compilations with autotools is to detect in configure.ac and define in Makefile.am. Using this method, detection of available libraries is done when the initial configure command executes and this conditionally creates a Makefile which only compiles source code if its dependencies are installed.

For example from the [gtkIOStream software's configure.ac detects the presence of jack](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/configure.ac#L301-L308). It then defines the variabel HAVE_JACK if it is present, like so :

```
# jack
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([JACK], [jack], HAVE_JACK="yes", HAVE_JACK="no")
AC_SUBST(JACK_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(JACK_LIBS)
AM_CONDITIONAL(HAVE_JACK, test x$HAVE_JACK = xyes)
if test "x$HAVE_JACK" == xyes ; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_JACK, [], [whether to build in Jack support])
fi
```

The [Makefile.am checks for the HAVE_JACK variable](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/applications/Makefile.am#L41-L43) and if it exists, it alters compilation. In your case this should work :

```
if HAVE_JACK
    myprog_SOURCES += src/jack_output.cc
endif
```

Now if configure detects jack, then your Makefile adds it to the sources to build.

If you want to limit ammplications from being built, then you will want to ammed a different variable (as for the previously mentioned gtkIOStream example) which looks like this :

```
if HAVE_JACK
bin_PROGRAMS += I2SEndianTest CrossoverTester
endif
```

gtkIOStream also detects ALSA like so :

```
# alsa
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(ALSA, alsa, HAVE_ALSA="yes", HAVE_ALSA="no")
AC_SUBST(ALSA_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(ALSA_LIBS)
AM_CONDITIONAL(HAVE_ALSA, test x$HAVE_ALSA = xyes)
if test "x$HAVE_ALSA" == xyes ; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_ALSA, [], [whether to build in Alsa support])
fi
```